# How can I alter the UI in a JQuery autocomplete box?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have a jquery autocomplete textbox.

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete#events

The spec there shows this:

Triggered when the suggestion menu is opened.
Code examples

Supply a callback function to handle the open event as an init option.

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
   open: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

I have that exact code and it works fine, but in the function I want to style the first list item.

```
$(ui).length is 1
$(ui).find('ul').length is 0
$(ui).find('li').length is 0
```

I can't figure out what ui is or how to use it. I can't use firebug because the popup dialogue disappears as soon as I click the firebug toolbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This selector should work:

```
ul.ui-autocomplete li:first-child
```

You can create a CSS rule with it.

Comment: Thanks, this is a last resort for me because I may have more than one on the page at once, although since they won't all be visible, at once it might be ok...

Answer (score 1):

Try to alert `$(ui).html()` and see what it contains, then you can use the right selector.

Comment: Tried this, but it is null... very odd!

Comment: Now you know what is happening so try to debug it and fine the root cause.

Comment: there's nothing to debug, my code is literally `open: function (event, ui) { alert($(ui).html()); }` so I guess ui must refer to something else, although how can the html be null if jquery picks it up?

Comment: I think ui is not a dom element because of which html() method is returning null. Try this selector to set the style for first element in the auto complete "ul.ui-autocomplete li:first-child" this might help you, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When I use "Inspect Element" on an option I get `<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">c++</a></li>`, so you may want to try styling either the `li` or `a` classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the end of the documentation there is a section on theming. I believe this gives an indication of what could be done.

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
   open: function(event, ui) { 
       $(".selector").find("li.ui-menu-item:first").css('your style here');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**ui** will only contain the suggestion that was selected.  To get the item that was selected, you could use :

```
var value = ui.item.value;
```

To style it, you will need to think of another way, for example:

```
$('.ui-menu-item:first').css('color','red');
```

Edit:  That's why ui is null when you simply alert it without selecting anything.